# Android Opengl ES Maximum number of textures

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, max

I am an Android developer and trying to use **OpenGL ES 1.0** for the first time to display a large number of square objects with a texture mapped onto them.
These textures are taken from large bitmaps, which I will probably scale down later.

Does anyone know how I can find out the **maximum number of textures** that my device will support (programmatically)?

I assume the maximum number will depend on things like the size and compression state of the textures. But I couldn't find any docs that mention what this limit is, or how to work it out.

I was hoping to be able to render **100,000** texture mapped square objects, and not sure if this is even possible on my device.

This is for a non-standard Android device so has no specs for things like this, if such a spec exists for officially released devices. It is a non-mobile bespoke device running **Android 4.1**, with 1 GB of memory.

Help or suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

You can get maximum number of Texture size available using

```
  int[] maxTextureSize = new int[1];
  GLES10.glGetIntegerv(GLES10.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, maxTextureSize, 0);
```

Your result will be in maxTextureSize[0]

Comment: Hi, I am after the maximum number of textures, not maximum texture size.

Comment: not sure.. but you can try : **GL_MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS**: it returns the maximum supported texture image units that can be used to access texture maps from the vertex shader.